# Removing columns from migration in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I created a table using migration like:

```
 Schema::create('listings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->decimal('original_price', 10, 2);
        $table->decimal('discouted_price', 10, 2);

        $table->integer('city_id')->index()->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');

        $table->integer('destination_city_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('destination_city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');

        $table->string('url');
        $table->string('titile');
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('expires_at');
        $table->integer('clicks')->default('0');
        $table->integer('views')->default('0');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

Now i wanna remove this two colums from ('listings').

```
$table->integer('city_id')->index()->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');

        $table->integer('destination_city_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('destination_city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
```

But someone can write the this new migration how must look for remove on this two columns ?

Comment: First drop the table from Database, then remove this lines from migration file and migrate again table using command: `php artisan migrate`

Comment: Nope, i must make a new migration for this. I dont must delete this two columns from listings table

Comment: To drop a column, you may use the `dropColumn` method on the Schema builder. Before dropping a column, be sure to add the `doctrine/dbal` dependency to your `composer.json` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function for hasColumn in Laravel Schema Builder in L5.8 is as follows:

```
\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder::hasColumn($table,$column)
{
 return in_array(
 strtolower($column), array_map('strtolower',$this->getColumnListing($table)));
```

so you should use your table name as the first parameter, like this

```
public function up() {

 if(Schema::hasColumn('listings','city_id')) {

    Schema::table('listings',function (Blueprint $table) {

      $table->dropColumn('city_id');

    });

  }

}
```

repeat for each column that you wish to drop

Answer (score 4):

You can do like this,

```
if (Schema::hasColumn('city_id', 'destination_city_id'))
{      
       $table->dropForeign('city_id');
       $table->dropForeign('destination_city_id');
       $table->dropColumn(['city_id', 'destination_city_id']);
}
```

Its always better to check if relavant column exists in table.

Give it a try, this should work.